# How to push my JMeter WEB DRIVER(Selenium Scripts) project to Azure Github Repository and run it via Azure Pipeline

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, performance-testing, azure-devops, cicd

Company requirements is to integrate **JMETER WEB DRIVER(SELENIUM SCRIPTS) with AZURE PIPELINE** so could anyone please help me the easy way process please?

In the VM the installed software's are below:
**1.JAVA(JRE,JDK) 2.GIT BASH 3.intelliJ**

Could anyone Please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all get familiarized with the [concept of the pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/what-is-azure-pipelines?view=azure-devops)

> Azure Pipelines **automatically** builds and tests code projects.

The key point is "automatically", you don't need "VM", "GIT BASH" and especially "intelliJ"

1. Create a JMeter .jmx script
2. Push it to your repository
3. Come up with a [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=java%2Ctfs-2018-2%2Cbrowser) which will:

   - Prepare the Azure pipeline runner like install JRE if it's not there
   - [Install JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-installation)
   - Install [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerAutomated/)
   - Run your JMeter test either in command-line [non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) or whatever is your favourite way of executing JMeter tests as long as it is not GUI
   - Fail the pipeline if [NFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement) acceptance criteria are not met
   - [Publish reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Comment: I have created a release pipeline with agent jobs - Install jmeter, command line and publish artifacts.
Now the pipeline is failing with error message - cmd exit with code 1. Also, Java Illegal arguments exception is thrown .
Logs - Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'D:\a\r1\a\_Performance\DMP JMeter(Web Driver)\DMP_CICD_LoadTest.jmx'. 
CannotResolveClassException: com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig  
I am not able to find out the **chromeconfig plugin for jmeter in AzurePipeline**. Can you please help me here?

Comment: You need to install [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager). See [Plugins Manager from Command-Line](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerAutomated/#Plugins-Manager-from-Command-Line) for more details.